# Use a dropdown select for the shipping address on the Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento2, layout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

In Magento 2, I would like to be able to select the shipping address with a dropdown, similar to how you can if you choose to change the billing address.

**This is how it currently works:**

[image]

**I would like it to work similarly to when you change the billing address, with a dropdown:**

[image]

I can see the dropdown for the billing address is set in:
`app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/list.html`

But I can't find the knockout template for the shipping address section, I thought it would be on of the files in:
`app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/`
or
`app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/`

But I couldn't find any here which worked.

Any ide

Comment: any module there for shipping section dropdown?

Comment: [![found valiable not initailised issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjGwi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjGwi.png)
found valiable not initailised issue found valiable not initailised issue

Answer (score 3):

The templates for shipping address section are here :

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/list.html`

and

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

You can override the same in your theme like this `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/list.html`

As you wish to list the addresses in select dropdown you need to change the code like this:

```
<div class="field field-select-shipping">
    <div class="control" >
        <select class="select" name="shipping_address_id" data-bind="
        options: addressOptions,
        optionsText: addressOptionsText,
        optionsValue: addressOptionsValue,
        value: selectedAddress,
        selectedOptions: selectedAddress,
        event: {change: selectAddress(selectedAddress())};
    "></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The js files are located here:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js`

and

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js`

You can override the same like this:
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-address/list.js`

You can refer to this file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js` for writing functions like `addressOptions`, `addressOptionsText` etc.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too, those were the template files I mentioned in my question.  But when I override them in my theme and clear the cache, nothing changes

Comment: actually, got it working. It was just the cache, but when I add your code I just get an empty select box

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you also need to write those functions called in the list.hyml file to get the values. You said you got it working. How did  you do ?

Comment: Is any one can got the output

Comment: @SejalShah what change js file please suggest me.

Comment: faced an issue like below image 
http://prntscr.com/nxzbgf
please help on this

Comment: @RamSampathi have you get any solution , I have same issue.